# Full Calendar Localization - "X more" is not translated

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using FullCalendar v6.1.11 with `locale: 'bg'` and "more" word on monthly grid, when you have more events for the day, is not translated.

Do you have some idea for proper way to do it?

Maybe in next releases will be fixed.

Comment: You can create a fork, fix it, and submit a PR. In FOSS, that's the proper way to do it.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features